# Cannot connect to a MYSQL instance from my Laravel 5.5 app both in the same GCloud project

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, laravel-5.5, gcloud

I'm trying to connect to my database stored in GCloud from a PHP Laravel 5.5 app in the same Gcloud project.

When I deploy my app, the homepage is displayed well but, when I try to connect the user, I get these errors that show on the browser:

[image: PDOException]
[image: QueryException]

I followed this tutorial: [Run Laravel on Google App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)

My app.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
document_root: public

skip_files:
 - .env

env_variables:
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_KEY: MY-APP-KEY
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
  SESSION_DRIVER: file
  DB_CONNECTION : mysql
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: MY DB NAME
  DB_USERNAME: USERNAME
  DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/MY-PROJECT-NAME:us-central1:MY-SQL-INSTANCE-NAME"
```

In the tutorial, they said to put this:

```
beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME"
```

But I removed it beacause when I run the command **gcloud app deploy**, I get this error: **An error occurred while parsing file : app.yaml at line xx column xx**

In my **database.php** file, I've tryed this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'DBNAME',
            'username' => 'USERNAME',
            'password' => 'PASWORD',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ]
```

And this (providing **unix_socket**):

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'DBNAME',
            'username' => 'USERNAME',
            'password' => 'PASSWORD',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/cloudsql/MY-PROJECT-NAME:us-central1:MY-SQL-INSTANCE-NAME'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ]
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT:

1. My API is enabled.
2. Billing is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Caner said, you have to keep the `beta_settings` part of the `app.yaml`, otherwise the database connection won't work, as in, I don't think the Cloud SQL Proxy executable will be included in the deployed app.

Besides this, you should also make sure that the account you're using for accessing the database has the correct grants for `@cloudsqlproxy~%`.

---

I've (successfully) tried deploying the default Laravel website (created via `laravel new`). The following snippets are for the latest version of Laravel (version 5.6), but from my testing this should work pretty much the same for 5.5.

Here's my `app.yaml` file. The user you'll be using for accessing the database should have grants for `@cloudsqlproxy~%` in the Cloud SQL instance. From my experimentation, the Cloud SQL Proxy runs in the AEF Compute Instances in Unix socket mode, so my guess is that at the end of the day, whatever you set in DB_HOST shouldn't really matter. Finally, be **very careful** with the spaces (actual spaces, not tabs) in the `app.yaml` file, and make sure you're not using some weird quotation mark character. And again, include `cloud_sql_instances` in `beta_settings`:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: INSERT_APPKEY_HERE
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  DB_DATABASE: laravel
  DB_USERNAME: INSERT_USERNAME
  DB_PASSWORD: INSERT_PASSWORD
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/project-name:region:cloudsql-instance-name"

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "project-name:region:cloudsql-instance-name"
```

Here's my `mysql` section of `config/database.php`. Mind you, I didn't change a thing, these are the default values for 5.6:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ]
```

Finally, here's the `post-install-cmd` section of the `composer.json` file. In 5.5, you also have to add `php artisan optimize` **before** the `chmod` command:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
    "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
]
```

Check if there's anything in your app's deployment settings that differs from what I'm posting here! The parsing error from your `gcloud app deploy` is very strange; as long as you format the file correctly and have gcloud up-to-date, it should work without issues.

Comment: From the begining, I was copying and pasting `beta_settings:` from the tutorial page. I wrote it by my self and now it works. Thanks guys, It was easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep this, it is vital:

```
beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME"
```

Replace "YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME" with connection name you see from the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances describe YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME
```

Also I'm not sure if this is a copy paste problem but you have missing spaces in your configuration before

```
runtime_config:
document_root: public # <- missing spaces here
```

Comment: I double checked my app.yaml file and I did not find missing spaces. I added this again: `beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME"` But I got the same message :(